# How to check if functions signatures are compatible in template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to create some template with virtual operator() as abstract interface and than to delegate some other class method with compatible signature as instance of that interface:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename rv_t, typename ... args_t>
struct IVirtualFunctionTemplate
{
    typedef rv_t (fsignature)(args_t ...);
    virtual rv_t operator()(args_t ...) = 0;
};

template<typename VF, typename rv_t, typename ... args_t>
struct SomeImpl :
    public VF
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename VF::fsignature, rv_t (args_t...)>::value, "Fail");

    template <class T>
    SomeImpl(T* t, rv_t (T::*method)(args_t...))
    {
    }

    rv_t operator()(args_t ... args) override
    {
        //...
        return rv_t();
    }
};

template <typename C, typename VF, typename rv_t, typename ... args_t>
void creator(VF *& delegate, C* that, rv_t (C::*method)(args_t...))
{
   delegate = new SomeImpl<VF, rv_t, args_t...>(that, method);
}
```

Now, I can use it like this:

```
struct ITest :
    public IVirtualFunctionTemplate<int, int>
{
};

struct Test
{
    int f(int a){ return a; }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    Test t;
    ITest* delegate = nullptr;
    creator(delegate, &t, &Test::f);
    int r = (*delegate)(42);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way than this:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<typename VF::fsignature, rv_t (args_t...)>::value, "Fail");
```

to check if functions signatures are compatible?

Comment: Personally, I think it's a bit problematic that changing this to `int f(float a){ return a; }` fails.

Comment: *'compatible'* and *'identical'* are not the same thing.

Comment: I know, that 'compatible' is not 'identical', but I don't know how to write compile-time checking for 'compatible'

Comment: If `rv_t` and `args_t` passed to `SomeImpl ` are not exactly the same as in `VF` (well, modulo covariant return types), this `SomeImpl` instantiation will fail to compile anyway, as a function declared with `override` will not in fact be an override. In light of this, I don't understand the point of all your gyrations.

Comment: Oh, really. Now I understood. The question can be considered closed.